# How to implement App with one Activity, few single Fragments and few fragments with Tabs?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello im creating an App where have to be few fragments just with listView and few with tabs. My current version works but has two activities, one replacing single fragments and another hosting tabs. Is there a possibility to implement just one activity with all kind off fragments?

TabHost Activity (example):

```
public class TaskListActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabsAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    new AdvanceActionBar(this, this.getSupportActionBar());
    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    adapter = new TabsAdapter( this, mViewPager );
    mViewPager.setAdapter( adapter );
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener( adapter );


    mViewPager.setId( 0x7F04FFF0 );

    mViewPager.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(mViewPager);

    addTab( "Do zrobienia", TaskListWaitingFragment.class, TaskListWaitingFragment.createBundle( "Do zrobienia") );
    addTab( "Do wysłania", TaskListSendFragment.class, TaskListSendFragment.createBundle( "Do wysłania") );
    addTab( "Weryfikacja", TaskListVerifyFragment.class, TaskListVerifyFragment.createBundle( "Weryfikacja") );
    addTab( "Odrzucone", TaskListRejectedFragment.class, TaskListRejectedFragment.createBundle( "Odrzucone") );


}
```

...

```
private class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private final SherlockFragmentActivity mActivity;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mPager;

    /**
     * @param fm
     * @param fragments
     */
    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        this.mPager = pager;

        mActionBar.setNavigationMode( ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS );
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private class TabInfo {
        public final Class fragmentClass;
        public final Bundle args;
        public TabInfo(Class fragmentClass,
                Bundle args) {
            this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
            this.args = args;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private List mTabs = new ArrayList();

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public void addTab( CharSequence title, Class fragmentClass, Bundle args ) {
        final TabInfo tabInfo = new TabInfo( fragmentClass, args );

        Tab tab = mActionBar.newTab();
        tab.setText( title );
        tab.setTabListener( this );
        tab.setTag( tabInfo );

        mTabs.add( tabInfo );

        mActionBar.addTab( tab );
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        final TabInfo tabInfo = (TabInfo) mTabs.get( position );
        return (Fragment) Fragment.instantiate( mActivity, tabInfo.fragmentClass.getName(), tabInfo.args );
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem( position );
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        TabInfo tabInfo = (TabInfo) tab.getTag();
        for ( int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++ ) {
            if ( mTabs.get( i ) == tabInfo ) {
                mPager.setCurrentItem( i );
            }
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

Standard Activity with fragments (Example):

```
public class CoreActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {



  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  }

  @Override
  public void onResume()
  {
      MessageFragment frag = new MessageFragment();
            this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag)
            .commit();

      super.onResume();  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use actionbarsherlock it's the easiest way to achieve what you want.

You can find usage and examples [here](http://actionbarsherlock.com/index.html).

Comment: I'm using it but how to switch that in activity?